# Rails 3.1 Passenger/Apache/force_ssl getting 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger

I'm trying to force my application into using SSL. I've inserted "force_ssl" into my application controller. However when I try to access the application I'm getting 404s for every page. The application is being redirected to https, though.

I'm using passenger and apache.

Is there something else I need to do? Any hints/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

into **application.rb**.